# Divide Sum of Unit Price by Sum of Quantity using Macro

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

[image: 1]

I am trying to add onto my current macro as I need to make the "Sum of Unit Price" to be the actual unit price which is the Quantity divide by the current Sum of Unit Price on the image attached.

How do I do this? Tried playing around with the PivotTable but no luck. I am happy for a new field to be applied just need the Unit Price to be there against each of the Model PC systems.

Comment: Try dragging the Unit Price field to the "Rows" area. Now it should be in both the "Rows" and in the "Values" areas. Does this give you what you want?

Comment: Is the unit price the same for all data-rows for a given product? If so, you can use Min or Max or Average, instead of Sum in the Value Field Settings->Summarise value Field by box. If the unit price can be different for the same product then your choices depend on how you construct this pivot table: you need to provide much more information.

Comment: Can we see an example of the raw data?  Added as text rather than an image.  https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#